# How do I get the onclick variable into a dialog function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a onclick event that has a value in it that I want to post to a backend php script. Just not sure how to get it in the dialog function.

```
function reorder(job_index)//<--------this fella
{
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 250,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Yes, use the number above': function() {
            var jobID=$("#jobnumber").val();
            $.post("rpc.php",   {           
                                job_index:job_index,// <-------to here          
                                jobID:jobID,
                                method: "reorder"
                                },
    function(data,textstatus)
        {
        alert(data.message);    
        }, "json");
            },
            'No, create a new number for me': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
        },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }

        }
    });
});
});
```

The value is job_index. Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: just a tip: you have a nested `read`y function inside your outer `ready` function. This is because `$(function() {` is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code, I'm using a single function that will allow you to both store and retrieve your index.

The function `index` is creating a [closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml) by returning declaring and returning another function.  This means that the variable `_index` will still be available (*think of it as like the variable was allocated on the heap instead of the stack-frame; ie malloc-ed*) once the (outer) function has returned, and as you can see the function is self-invoking, due to the `}();` on the last line of the function, thus returning immediately during parsing.

Then when you call the function `index` again (which now you will be basically calling the inner function that takes one formal argument, `ind`), you can pass in your index and if you do, the function will store it in the `_index` variable that I mentioned earlier on...ie the variable that is still available after the outer function returned.

If you don't pass in an argument (ie invoke the function like such: `index()`), the function only returns your stored variable.  The logic behind this is that if a parameter is not passed, the value of the actual argument is `undefined`.  Thus the function checks if the value is `undefined`, and if it is, it justs returns your variable.

And btw, you have a nested `ready` function inside your outer `ready` function.  This is because `$(function() {` is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){`.  I fixed this in the below code:

```
var index = function () {
    var _index;
    return function (ind) {
        if (typeof ind !== "undefined") {
            _index = ind;
        }
        return _index;
    };
}();

function reorder(job_index)
{
    index(job_index);
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}

$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 250,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Yes, use the number above': function () {
                var jobID = $("#jobnumber").val();
                $.post("rpc.php", {
                    job_index: index(),                 
                    jobID: jobID,
                    method: "reorder"
                },

                function (data, textstatus) {
                    alert(data.message);
                },
                "json");
            },
            'No, create a new number for me': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }

        }
    });
});
```

---

Another way to do it is by using the `data` method that [nickf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893093/how-do-i-get-the-onclick-variable-into-a-dialog-function/1893111#1893111) mentioned.  This will allow you to store the index directly as part of your element, like such:

```
function reorder(job_index)
{
    $('#dialog').data("job", job_index).dialog('open');
}

$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 250,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Yes, use the number above': function () {
                var jobID = $("#jobnumber").val();
                $.post("rpc.php", {
                    job_index: $("#dialog").data("job"),                 
                    jobID: jobID,
                    method: "reorder"
                },

                function (data, textstatus) {
                    alert(data.message);
                },
                "json");
            },
            'No, create a new number for me': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store it as data on the element using `.data()`

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable, store the last clicked job_index there, and read it from there in the click handler.

```
var last_job_index;
function reorder(job_index)
{
    last_job_index = job_index;
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}
//snip
$.post("rpc.php",  {                       
    job_index: last_job_index,
    jobID: jobID,
    method: "reorder"
},
```

Warning: This is quite an unprofessional solution (shared mutable state)